# I have a problem passing data through an interface

Tags: java, android

I want to pass data from `Activity` to `DialogFragment` using `interface`. I have succeeded when pass data from `Adapter` to `Fragment` with code some like bellow
But i have a error  `java.lang.NullPointerException` with code bellow when i pass data from `Activity` to `DialogFragment`

I have a Activity

```
 public class TheLoaiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView, recyclerView1;
AdapterTruyen adapterTruyen;
List<modelTruyen> listTruyen;
List<modelKinds> listKinds;
LinearLayout lnTheloai;
private OnClickIntent mListener;
int id;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.kinds_layout);
    addControl();
    id = getIntent().getIntExtra(AdapterKinds.KEY_INTENT_DATA_KINDS,0);
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    loadData();
    loadView(id);
    addEvents();
}

private void addEvents() {
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    final TheLoaiDialogFragment dialogFragment = new TheLoaiDialogFragment();
    lnTheloai.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onClick(listKinds);  //ERROR at here
            dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager,"list_kind");
        }
    });
}
public interface OnClickIntent {
    void onClick(List<modelKinds> list);
}

// set the listener. Must be called from the fragment
public void setListener(OnClickIntent listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}
```

and `DialogFragment`

```
public class TheLoaiDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
AdapterKinds adapterKinds;
List<modelKinds> listKinds;
TextView txtCancel;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kinds_fragment_layout,container,false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_diaglogFragmentKinds);
    txtCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_camcelKindsFragment);

    TheLoaiActivity theLoaiActivity = new TheLoaiActivity();
    theLoaiActivity.setListener(new TheLoaiActivity.OnClickIntent() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(List<modelKinds> list) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: "+ list.size());
        }
    });
```

When i pass data from `Activity` to `DiaglogFragment` i have a problem this is

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.abba.story, PID: 18048
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.abba.kinds.TheLoaiActivity$OnClickIntent.onClick(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
```

What should i do?
Can you explain for me about this error ?

Comment: Seems that a call is attempted *before* having the listener set. You should check for nulls here.

Comment: So you want to pass `listKinds` variable from Activity to Dialog. Can you show me `modelKinds` class?

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment, replace:

```
TheLoaiActivity theLoaiActivity = new TheLoaiActivity();
```

with:

```
TheLoaiActivity theLoaiActivity=(TheLoaiActivity)getActivity();
```

Comment: Sorry, you're right, please check the updated answer

Comment: Sorry guy. Your code is nothing changes.Still an error NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

To get a reference to the parent activity inside a Fragment you need to make the calls inside the **onActivityCreated** method. Before it, for example in **onCreateView**, the Activity does not exist and that's why you're getting the null pointer exception. Plus you're creating a NEW activity not getting a reference to the already existing Activity where the fragment is contained

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    TheLoaiActivity theLoaiActivity = (TheLoaiActivity)getActivity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work for sure

```
private void addEvents() {
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    final TheLoaiDialogFragment dialogFragment = new TheLoaiDialogFragment();
    lnTheloai.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //ERROR at here
            dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager,"list_kind");
        }
    });
}
public interface OnClickIntent {
    void onClick(List<modelKinds> list);
}

// set the listener. Must be called from the fragment
public void setListener(OnClickIntent listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
if(mListener !=null){
   mListener.onClick(listKinds);
}

}
```